# Access all checkboxes in Request.Form object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

Can someone please explain how to get values from all check boxes with the same name attribute from Request.Form object?

I have a View which has a List model. When I iterate through items, I display a `Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.SomeBoolValue)`. Razor renders that value as a name of each `checkbox` element.

On the server-side, in a Controller, I try to extract the information with `Request.Form.Get("item.SomeBoolValue")`. It returns a series of **true**s and **false**s in a string. But when I try to access check boxes by index (`Request.Form.Get("item.SomeBoolValue")[i]`), it returns a weird code (*102f* or *97a*, for example).

How should I properly get values from check boxes needed for my logic? Please help, I am going crazy about this. Searched everywhere, tried everything.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for collection items. Use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)) And do no use `Request.Form` - bind to your model!

Comment: I am not trying to generate form controls, I am trying to extract posted values on the server-side.

Also, I am using `Request.Form` only because it won't bind no matter what I do. I put everything in a `@Html.BeginForm`, my `input` element is of type `submit`, so I couldn't figure that out and this looked more promising.

Comment: You are generating form controls - what do you think `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` does. Read the dupe!

Comment: Oh, that... I am using a loop in a Controller action, too, so I misunderstood. Thank you very much, I will look into it.